# clippy error when using uri! macro with a placeholder named as a local binding

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

This code compiles and works perfectly fine:

```
use rocket::{get, uri};

#[get("/test/<x>")]
pub fn endpoint(x: i32) -> &'static str {
    let _x = x;
    "x"
}

fn main() {
    let x = 123;
    let query = uri!(endpoint(x = x));
    println!("{}", query)
}
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "dd"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc"
```

But when I run `cargo clippy`, it fails with:

```
error: redundant redefinition of a binding
  --> src/main.rs:10:9
   |
10 |     let x = 123;
   |         ^
11 |     let query = uri!(endpoint(x = x));
   |                                   ^
   |
   = help: remove the redefinition of `x`
   = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#redundant_locals
   = note: `#[deny(clippy::redundant_locals)]` on by default

error: could not compile `dd` (bin "dd") due to previous error
```

And the error doesn't really seem to make sense.
Renaming the `x` binding resolves the issue.

**Could this be a bug in clippy, or is it a problem with the `uri!` macro? Or the code above, maybe?**

Relevant info:

- this lint `redundant_locals` was only introduced in 1.73, the problem did not exist in 1.72,
- maybe rocket is at fault here (problem in the macro), but I would expect the clippy error to refer to the macro, not the caller.

Comment: Whether it is a bug in Clippy or in the `uri!()` macro depends on convention, but by convention usually Clippy is right and the macro should disable the lint (unless the lint is in general not applicable to macro-expanded code, in which case Clippy is in fault).

Comment: This is a result of the `uri!` expansion. I've opened a PR to add an `allow` attribute to it: https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/pull/2630.

Comment: @isaactfa Oh, that makes sense now